# Party with Local and Remote Members - PS4

Tags: diablo-iii, ps4

Party with 4 members playing Diablo III on PlayStation 4:

- Player 1 (machine 1)
- Player 2 (machine 1)
- Player 3 (machine 2)
- Player 4 (machine 3)

Do Player 3 & 4 see that Player 2 is playing on the same machine as Player 1?

Don't ask me why this is important, short answer: I don't want Player 3 & 4 to know that Player 2 is at my place. Weird, I know.

A Screenshot would be wonderful. I can't try it myself, since Player 3 & 4 (or anyone else with D3) do not have 2 controllers.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no indication on how players are connected - only that they are part of the same party.

On a way for THEM to figure it out, if they were somehow able to flood your IP and lag you out of the game, they would see that both Player 1 and Player 2 would disconnect at the same time, indicating that you are playing from the same IP address.

Other than that, there is no way to tell in-game.